# Bulk Insert with Table Valued Parameter not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Need to insert multiple records into a SQL table. If there are duplicates (already inserted records) then I want to ignore them. For sending multiple records from my code to SQL, I am using table valued parameter.

Below is the query. It works during the first insertion when there are no rows in the table. On subsequent insert, no rows are added.

@tvpNewFMdata is the table valued parameter.

```
INSERT INTO
        [dbo].[FMData]
        (
            [Id],
            [Name],
            [Path],
            [CreatedDate],
            [ModifiedDate]
        )
    SELECT 
        fm.Id, fm.Name, fm.Path, GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE() 
    FROM 
        @tvpNewFMdata AS fm
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT 
            tbl.[Id] 
        FROM 
            [dbo].[FMdata] AS tbl
        WHERE
            tbl.Id = fm.Id
        )
```

I am unable to locate as to what the cause that the first time insertion works but not the second time.

Tried with even removing the WHERE NOT EXISTS clause and it was only working in the first insertion. Subsequent insertion is not adding any rows to the table.

Comment: Maybe because the ID is already there?

Comment: The ID is unique. First time the ID is in the range 1 to 10 and then the second insert the ID is 15 to 25

Comment: "bulk insert" has a specific meaning within SQL Server, and what you're doing isn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an error, or just no rows inserted?  If there are just no rows being inserted, even with the removed where clause, it sounds like you might be having problems populating the table value param.  Have you watched what you are sending into SQL via a breakpoint or SQL Server Profiler?

Instead of where exists, have you tried a left join to fmData, and only inserting where the fmData row is null?

I agree with Damien, this is not bulk insert.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. My apologies. It was a mistake in my code. There was no issue in the SPROC. I was parameterizing the function and was passing the wrong table valued parameter.